# Getting 404 http error during ajax call in GAE java project

Tags: ajax, google-app-engine, http, http-status-code-404

I want to call a java class on click of the submit button in jsp. it shows me the 404 error. I guess the url which I am passing in ajax call is wrong but I am unable to figure out the right url.

my java class is in a package in src folder and jsp is in sub folder inside war folder of GAE project.

My ajax code is here:

```
var form = $('#submitForm1');

form.submit(function() {
    alert(form.attr('action'))
    $.ajax({
        type : form.attr('method'),
        url : form.attr('action'),
        data : form.serialize(),
        success : function(data) {
            alert("success..");
            alert(data);
        },
        error : function(data) {
            alert("error");
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: this is the form tag of my jsp which is submitted: <form id="submitForm1" name="submitForm1" action="abcJavaClass" method="POST">

Comment: Please provide the web.xml to show the mapping for the abcJavaClass action. This will help us understand if you have mapped the same in the web.xml or not ?

Comment: This is the entry made in web.xml:                           <servlet>
     <servlet-name>abcJavaClass</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>com.example.abcJavaClass</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>abcJavaClass</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/abcJavaClass</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

Comment: my jsp url is: http://localhost:8080/sp/contactUs.jsp and when i submit form the url which is displayed in firebug  is http://localhost:8080/sp/abcJavaClass  where as my class is not in sp folder, it is in src package, may be this is the problem.. but i dont know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your `web.xml` is defined the way you have specified, you can try a couple of approaches:

- As per your `web.xml` mappings, the path that your Servlet is available at is `/abcJavaClass` whereas your JSP file is inside of the subfolder `/sp`, so it is looking inside of /sp/abcJavaClass. One option to just make it work is to move your JSP file to a folder above `/sp`.
- Alternately, change the `url-pattern` to `sp/abcJavaClass`

Any of the above should work out for you. You will need to make a choice on which one you would want to go with. I also suggest that you name you classes and actions, more intuitively when you eventually go beyond your learning phase. It will help you maintain the code much better. For e.g. instead of `abcJavaClass`, name it to what it actually does.